# View binding Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple app where you can login it looks like this:

```
{{#view App.mainV}}
  {{#if logged}}
     Hey!
  {{else}}
  <!-- Login form here when clicked: App.mainC.login()-->
  {{/if}}
{{/view}}
```

Here is sample controller:

```
App.mainC = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    login: function(){
        if(ok)//Everything went fine
            App.mainV.logged = true;
    }
});
```

Here is mainV:

```
App.mainV = Ember.View.extend({
    logged: false,
    test: function()
    {
        console.log('JO');
    }
});
```

I have two questions regarding this app:

- Why when I change logged to true view doesn't change?
- If I call App.mainV.test() I get an error. Why?

  TypeError: 'App.mainV.test' is not a function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access a view's property from a template, you have to prefix with "view." In your example: `{{#if view.logged}}`.

You can't do `App.mainV.test()` because `App.mainV` is a class, not an instance. You could do `App.mainV.create().test()`.

And you should rename `App.mainV` to `App.MainV` to fit Ember.js conventions (class names should be capitalized, see http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html)

**Edit**:

There's another problem in your example: the controller tries to modify a value in the view. In the Ember way, you should bind a view's property to the controller. Any change in the controller would be propagated to the view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#view App.MainView}}
    {{#if view.logged}}
        Hey!
    {{else}}
        <!-- Login form here when clicked: App.mainController.login()-->
    {{/if}}
{{/view}}
</script>​

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.mainController = Ember.Controller.create({
    logged: false,
    login: function() {
        this.set('logged', true);
    }
});

App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
    loggedBinding: 'App.mainController.logged'
});

// change in controller will be propagated to the view
App.mainController.set('lo​gged', true);​​​​​​
```

Comment: I can access access to "logged", but when it's changed, view doesn't update.

Comment: I've recently had an issue like this, but to minimize coupling I needed a relative binding from my view to my controller, i.e. `loggedBinding: 'controller.logged'`. This didn't work (though I don't know why). What I found worked instead was setting up a computed property in the view: `logged: Ember.computed.alias('controller.logged')`